# Koken doesn't load on DigitalOcean

Tags: digital-ocean, koken

Yesterday I decided to take a snapshot from my DigitalOcean droplet running Koken (using Docker), so I turned the droplet off (using the bash command "poweroff") and took the snapshot (through the admin panel). The droplet has apparently turned on automatically after the completion of the snapshot, but it's not running Koken I guess, because I can access the droplet using SSH, but I can't load my website in any browser. Also the memory usage of the droplet is low (11%), while when it was working properly it was 38%. Firefox displays the error page "unable to connect". How can I start Koken again?

By the way, I think my database/files are still in place. How can I take a copy of my data (especially my essays and my pages), and restore them after re-installing Koken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got an answer from DigitalOcean support team. You can start Koken using this command (Docker script):

```
docker run -p 80:8080 -v /data/koken/www:/usr/share/nginx/www -v /data/koken/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -d koken/koken-lemp /sbin/my_init
```